# What does this say

Tags: translation

[image]

Can you please tell me what this says and, if you can write it so, I can copy and paste it would be great

Comment: Japanese name: 加藤直樹 (Naoki Kato)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like:

加藤 Jiā​téng： Katō (Japanese surname）
直 zhí：straight
樹 shù: tree

Someone's name perhaps?